# Image from Desktop not displaying (Java)

Tags: java, user-interface, imageicon

```
public model()
{
    setTitle("Model");
    p1 = new JPanel();

    ImageIcon ig = new ImageIcon("C:\\Desktop\\ELON.gif");
    JLabel l1 = new JLabel("Tesla", ig, SwingConstants.RIGHT);

    p1.add(l1);
    add(p1);
    setVisible(true);
}
```

Code is compiling but no image is shown.
Image is saved on my desktop.

Please help :(

Comment: Right-Click on the file you need and select Properties. Click on the tab that says "Details" and there you see the path you need. Because "Desktop" is not directly on the "C:" partition. It's in your user folder. Refer to @MordechayS answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
ImageIcon ig = new ImageIcon("c://users//**username**\\ELON.gif");
```

And next time - debug. :)

Comment: Hi Mordechay S,

Comment: public image()
    {
        setTitle("Tesla Motors Inc");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        panel = new JPanel();
        ImageIcon ig = new ImageIcon("c://users//KITS SG\\elon.jpeg");
        label = new JLabel("Tesla", ig, SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        
        panel.add(label);
        add(panel);
        
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

Comment: Please add the code in your question and attach an image of your frame...

Answer (score 0):

The file path is most certainly wrong (as MordechayS already noted).

**Passing file (or more general: resource) paths around as String is error prone**. `ImageIcon`, as you already noted, does *not* throw an exception when there's no such file (it just displays nothing).

You can improve your code by passing the icon resource as `File`, or (as `File` is not supported directly in `ImageIcon`): `URL`. **URLs have the advantage that it can point to a File, a web resource, a resource within a JAR file**, and more.

```
File resource = new File("C:\\Users\\myself\\Desktop\\ELON.gif");
// now you can verify the resurce using File.exists(), File.canRead() and File.isFile()

// convert to file URL
URL url = resource.toURI().toURL(); 
ImageIcon ig = new ImageIcon(url);
```

Comment: Hi Peter,


Thanks for your answer.

Comment: However, I'm getting an error: "cannot find symbol - method toURL()" and that "toURL() in java.io.File has been deprecated.

How do I resolve this?

NOTE: I've import java.io.File & java.net.*;

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the path error, you don't have `pack()`...... Next time before `setVisible()`, use `pack()`.

I suggest to read Oracle tutorial. Too much to read, but "slow is fast".

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html